# Aside in Dummit & Foote after the Second Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group, let $A \leq G$, and let $B \trianglelefteq G$. Then the Second Isomorphism Theorem says that $AB/B \cong A / A \cap B$. In a remark after the proof (page 98), D&F say that we also have in general that $|AB : A| = |B: A \cap B|$. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The isomorphism $AB/B \cong A/(A \cap B)$ and the fact that the cosets of a subgroup form a partition of the whole group give $$\begin{aligned}|AB/B| = |A/(A \cap B)| &\implies \frac{|AB|}{|B|} = \frac{|A|}{|A \cap B|} \\ &\implies \frac{|AB|}{|A|} = \frac{|B|}{|A \cap B|} \\&\implies |AB : A| = |B : A \cap B|\end{aligned}$$

Edit: As mentioned by Arturo Magidin this argument works in the case where $A$ and $B$ are finite. For the general case, Ted Shifrin's suggested map gives a bijection.

Define $\varphi:B/(A \cap B) \to AB/A$ by $\varphi(b(A \cap B)) = bA$ (note that this is a function on the set of cosets and not necessarily on a quotient group). $\varphi$ is both well-defined and injective since for any $b_1, b_2 \in B$ we have $$b_1 A = b_2 A \iff b_1^{-1}b_2 \in A \iff b_1^{-1}b_2 \in A \cap B \iff b_1(A \cap B) = b_2(A \cap B).$$

Since $A$ normalizes $B$, any element of $AB/A$ is of the form $bA$ for some $b \in B$. We have that $\varphi(b(A \cap B)) = bA$ for any $b \in B$ so $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: Of course, this assumes all quantities are finite; but the assertion holds even when the indices and cardinalities are infinite.

Comment: But it won't be a group homomorphism in general. Nevertheless, the map $\varphi$ induces a bijection between the two sets of cosets.

Comment: @User2533488 How do you deal with the case when the indices are infinite, as ArturoMagidin pointed out? In that case your chain of implications breaks down and so your conclusion can't be reached.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. This was a good lesson for me in that I should be more careful when posting answers.

Comment: I would strongly advice you to use cosets on the same side for both sets of cosets. In particular, your last implication is false as written: from $b_1b_2^{-1}\in A\cap B$ you cannot conclude $b_1(A\cap B) = b_2(A\cap B)$, nor can you use the latter to conclude the former. You get $b_1^{-1}b_2\in A\cap B$, but not $b_1b_2^{-1}\in A\cap B$.

Comment: Thank you for catching that as well. I have fixed it.